# is there a way to pass php variable with div id?

Tags: php, html, css

i'm trying to pass a pass php value through "href" from one div to another div.

As we can do this from one page to another like

```
<a href="somepage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"></a>
```

is there a way to do it using id(css selector)
for ex:

```
<div id="div1">
<a href="#div2?id=<php echo $id?>"></a>
</div>
```

can you please suggest a way to where i can pass a php value through "href" from one division to another division in the same page

Comment: maybe this will help? http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Comment: You're missing the `?` in `<?php`.

Comment: sorry for that typing error. i've corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Sure you can. Just use the # in the link. It will tell browser that the link is pointing to an element on the same page.

```
<!-- Link pointing to target Div -->
<a href="#div<?php echo $id; ?>">Click here to scroll to target div</a>

<!-- Target Div -->
<div id="div<?php echo $id; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: the link isn't working if i put the php code but works fine with just #div. is there any other way that i could do this

Comment: That might be because of the id value. Are you sure your `id` value is being echoed out properly. Otherwise the code should work

Comment: You are welcome. And if your problem is resolved, then please feel free to tick the answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: Will do it. But i cant upvote coz my points are very low and it won't consider my vote

Comment: Thanks. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. Pass your php id to your div

```
<a href="#div<php echo $id?>"></a><div id="div<?php echo $id ?>"></div>
```